# custom post type pagination don't work with rewrite pagination_base

Tags: pagination, custom-post-type

this is my first ask. Thanks for support.

I created custom post type and everything works fine but pagination of my archive-customposttypename.php pagination don't work. I changed pagination base with a simple plugin found on internet, in this site:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Page to Seite
 * Description: Ersetzt <code>/page/</code> durch <code>/seite/</code>.
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz <info@toscho.de>
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 't5_page_to_seite' ) )
{
register_activation_hook(   __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
add_action( 'init', 't5_page_to_seite' );

function t5_page_to_seite()
{
$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->pagination_base = 'pagina';
}
function t5_flush_rewrite_on_init()
{
add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules', 11 );
}
}
```

Where is the problem? If i deactive plugin and use default pagination_base (page) works fine. Any idea?

Comment: Its a very common issue and have lots of answer available already http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pagination+not+working+for+Custom+post+type

Comment: @boom_Shiva I tried all formats for fix this problem. Include install Types for created custom post types automatic but ever the same error. http://www.buscatuppersex.com/noticias/ page 2 not work, only if i restore default pagination "page". can you help me please?

Comment: I'm really desperated. hours and nothing... i don't have eyes for today

Comment: are you using some custom code or still the same plugin? if you are using some other code can you please provide it here.

Comment: Just save the Permalinks again and deactivate other plugins except this one

Comment: i use this plugin and add RedirectMatch Permanent ^/(.*)/page/(.*) /$1/pagina/$2 to .htaccess nothing more. How can save the permalinks again? you can see the error here http://www.buscatuppersex.com/noticias/ @boom_Shiva many thanks for help

Comment: From settings option, Navigate to permalinks and save it to Post Name.

Comment: thanks but that is right. checked again but not resolve the problem. any idea?

Comment: Problem solved! delete plugin and .httaccess line and install WP htaccess Control Plugin. Change pagination base to "pagina" and work! really thanks for all @boom_Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! delete plugin and .httaccess line and install WP htaccess Control Plugin. Change pagination base to "pagina" and work!